# Error while deploying react js and node app to aws

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my app to aws, i search and i found alot of tutorials i try each one and i get this error on the browser:

> Cannot GET /

I figure maybe that my problem is from my nodeJS server code.

This is my server.js code hope you guys can help me thanks.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

//Api routes
const users = require('./routes/api/usuario');
const alumno = require('./routes/api/alumno');
const personal = require('./routes/api/personal');
const zonas = require('./routes/api/zonas');
const sepomex = require('./routes/api/sepomex');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
//Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Db config
const db = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? require('./config/keys').mongoURIProd : require('./config/keys').mongoURIDev;

//connect to mongo DB
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
//passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Use routes

app.use('/api/usuario', users);
app.use('/api/alumno', alumno);
app.use('/api/personal', personal);
app.use('/api/zonas', zonas);
app.use('/api/sepomex', sepomex);


//serve static assets to production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    //static folder
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));

    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have deployed my app on heroku and works fine.

Comment: Does the console of the browser show any other errors?

Comment: Yeah, 404 Not found

Comment: While deploying your app, and it's finished with bundling everything, does it produce an error?

Comment: No, the errors appears after the deploy when i want to access to my app

Comment: Presumably you see "Server running on port N" when you run your node app. What happens if you run "curl localhost:5000" (or whatever your port number is), does it work?

Comment: `< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 10:21:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 139
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to EC2 instance then you need to specify IP address in `app.listen` to be `0.0.0.0`, by default it is set to localhost which is not what you want if you want the app to be reachable from outside.

You should change your code to

```
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6

So i need to change the default ip address to my private ip address?

Comment: Sure, if you are using Nginx with those settings then you need to change its configuration to use private IP address of the instance.